# How to bind a component with an object in view scoped managed bean?

Tags: jsf, managed-bean, icefaces

I am trying to create a dynamic panel (panel with various items) then i want to bind it with panel component in view page, the scope of managed bean which has the panel object is `@ViewScoped`.
I noticed  that any `ajax` render this panel in the view page rebuild the managed bean, Why is that ?
Here is my code :

this is the managed bean :

```
package test;

import org.icefaces.ace.component.panel.Panel;

@ManagedBean(name = "myBean")
@ViewScoped

public class myBean  {

    private Panel myPanel;

    // Constructor
    public myBean() {
         myPanel = drawPanel(); // this function initiate and add items to the panel 
    }

    // Setters and Getters Methods
}
```

and this the view page :

```
<h:form>
    <ace:panel binding="#{myBean.myPanel}"></ace:panel>
    <ace:pushButton actionListener="#{myBean.something}">
        <ace:ajax render="@form" />
    </ace:pushButton>
</h:form>
```

in every time i pressed the button, the managed bean constructor invoked , Why does that happened ? 
Also i noticed that if i remove the binding attribute from the panel component or make the scope of the managed bean session or application scope, the constructor didn't invoked.

Note : I am using icefaces 3 and jsf 2.0 .

Is there any solution for this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

As the ICEFaces documentation says:

> The Push Button is a component that allows entry of a complete form or just itself. It has the same functionality of a regular jsf command button but without having to add extra attributes.

Because the PushButton is a command button it do navigation. If you don't use its action attribute it will apply its default value. I can't find what it is (I just suspect that it is an empty string).

The JSF navigation rules depending on the action outcome of UICommands:

- **null or void** : reloads the current view
- **empty string** : recreates the current view (if the view recreated, the view scoped beans do the same)
- **non empty string** : the next view determined by the navigation handler.

If the reason is the empty string default result of the action attribute, then use it in the facet:

```
<ace:pushButton action="#{myBean.nextPage}" actionListener="#{myBean.something}">
```

And pass back a null value in its linked handler method:

```
public class MyBean // You use myBean here in your question improperly
{
  public String nexPage()
  { return null; }
}
```